# jitsu throws import error - can't figure out why

Tags: maas

juju already installed and running with juju-gui on my MAAS local cloud.
can't figure why jitsu can't start:

```
root@maas:~# jitsu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jitsu", line 23, in <module>
    from juju.control import JujuFormatter
ImportError: No module named juju.control
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - solved - found out jitsu is not supported with juju-core.
used 'juju deploy --to' for my purpose..

Comment: Could you please check the green mark next to your answer to mark your question as solved? Thanks!